# How to write lucene query for finding minimum of some element?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-3

I want to add a filter in kibana something like (*- (value < 21))[Records which have <21 value atleast one time]. So In this case we cant apply filter (* AND (value >21)) because value is dynamic variable because (* AND (value >21)) will give the records which have value >21 atleast once so it will give some records which had value <21 some time and > 21 some time.
SO i Want to extract inverse of records which have value <21 even for one time throught the range given.

Comment: I really didnt get this. Can you show an example?